# SEO: Google Search Console Redirect

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

i'm facing some serious problems when I try to myke our multilangual website SEO friendly.

When you access our website

```
https://url.com
```

You get immediately redirected by your current browser local or existing session local. There are four options.

```
https://url.com/en 
https://url.com/fr
https://url.com/de
https://url.com/it
```

**Google Search Console**
I've played around with the Fetch as Google section within the Google Search Console. Of course accessing via an empty local parameter will redirect you.

```
https://url.com => Redirected
https://url.com/de => Partial
```

[image: SEO Problem]
We're facing the problem, that only a part of the links within the sitemap are published and if their published its some wild mix between the different languages.

I also provide a sitemap.xml with the following structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<url>
    <loc>https://url/de</loc>
    <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="de"
            href="https://url/de"/>
    <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="fr"
            href="https://url/fr"/>
    <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="it"
            href="https://url/it"/>
    <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="en"
            href="https://url/en"/>
</url>
```

And also submitted a robots.txt file.

```
User-Agent: *

Sitemap: https://url/sitemap.xml

Allow: /sitemap.xml

Allow: /
Allow: /imprint

Allow: /de
Allow: /de/imprint
```

There is also a meta tag for alternate:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de_de" href="{{ config('app.url') .'/de' }}"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr_fr" href="{{ config('app.url') .'/fr' }}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="it_it" href="{{ config('app.url') .'/it' }}" />
```

Any suggestions what I need to change to get the SEO properly configuratet?

Comment: This isn't the cause of the problem, but there is no need to use `Allow:` in robots.txt.  Allowing is the default behavior.  Unless you have disallowed something and want to allow a subset, there is no reason to use `Allow:`.  Even then, not all robots understand the `Allow:` directive.   Google understands it, but it is non-standard.  I'm not even sure if other search engines support it.

Comment: When you say that not all links are published, do you mean that your entire site isn't translated, and when a user visits a page that is untranslated, parts of that page show the default language?

Comment: I'm also not sure exactly what the SEO problem you are facing is.  You don't describe what Google is doing wrong.  The only thing you say is that fetch as Google is showing redirected when appropriate.